# импорт из html и txt в php и обратно

Tags: php, html

Добрый день!

Есть txt файл

```
Имя|id
Вася|5
Петя|8
Таня|6
Катя|4
```

Есть код

```
$id = 6;
$page_content = file("rs.txt");
foreach($page_content AS $value)
{
    $result = explode("|", $value);

    $name = $result[0];
    $user_id = $result[1];

    if( $id == $user_id )
        echo $name;
}
```

есть разметка html

```
<div id="6">echo $name;</div>
<div id="8">echo $name;</div>
<div id="4">echo $name;</div>
<div id="5">echo $name;</div>
```

Мне нужно доделать код, чтобы при равенстве id у дива и $user_id из кода, между дивами появлялся соответствующий код
как заменить $id = 6; на значение id у дива?
код найдет все дивы с id и сравнит их значение $user_id

В итоге я должна получить

```
Таня
Петя
Катя
Вася
```

у каждого дива свой стиль, значений будет более 100
я могу поместить код php внутрь дива и получить желаемый результат, только меняться будет только цифра $id = ""; и код выйдет километровый

Comment: Если вы хотите сравнивать id, то вам нужно их хотя бы вытянуть с div(это уже, как минимум js,jQuery).
Проще уже в самом цикле foreach вместо проверки $id == $user_id(в самом if ошибка, т.к. вы не добавили фигурные скобки) выводить <div id="<?php echo $user_id; ?>"><?php echo $name; ?></div>

Comment: @Denis Lazarev `if` можно и без фигурных скобок писать, это не является ошибкой, и код условия будет выполняться до ближайшей точки с запятой.

Comment: @Эдуард За if прочитал. Был неправ, спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

правильный код разметки html

```
<div id="6"><?php  echo $name; ?></div>
<div id="8"><?php  echo $name; ?></div>
<div id="4"><?php  echo $name; ?></div>
<div id="5"><?php  echo $name; ?></div>
```

и id будут иметь не числовые значения, id_1, id_2 и тд